# How to create .exe using pyinstaller for a multipage streamlit application

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, streamlit

I am trying to create an .exe file for my streamlit multipage app so that user can run this app on their desktop without worrying about python and other dependences.

i am able to run single page streamlit app as an .exe following the step mentioned in this repo
https://github.com/jvcss/PyInstallerStreamlit/tree/master

Additional what i  want is if i wanted to add pages under the folder pages (additional streamlit pages like page_1.py, page_2.py) along with my app.py then all 3 pages should be available in the web browser.(app.py, page_1.py,page_2.py).

Right now only app.py is getting displayed and not page_1 and page_2.

Anyone has tried out anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a self-contained exe file, another alternative is to use [stlite](https://github.com/whitphx/stlite):

> A port of Streamlit to WebAssembly, powered by Pyodide.
>
> Streamlit is a Python web app framework for the fast development of data apps. This project is to make it run completely on web browsers.

With it, you can create a serverless version of your Streamlit app and just send the URL. If you are specifically interested in a desktop app, you can even bundle it with Electron following [these instructions](https://github.com/whitphx/stlite/blob/main/packages/desktop/README.md).

A more involved option is to use [Streamlit Cloud](https://blog.streamlit.io/host-your-streamlit-app-for-free/).

P.S.: I know this does not answer OP's question exactly, but I found it relevant enough to add it as an answer.